# Change File Value in CPU Folder

Tags: shell, android-emulator, cpu

i want to change value in sched_mc_power_savings file, using this code :

```
   #!/system/bin/sh
   mount -o remount,rw /
   mount -o remount,rw /system
   busybox echo "4" > /sys/device/system/cpu/sched_mc_power_savings
```

but it not work, and it always give an error like

/etc/init.d/00myfile 
: not found

or

can't create /sys/device/system/cpu/sched_mc_power_savings
: no such file or directory

and i though using busybox echo to change the value is enough, so does im doing something wrong ? and how make it works ?

Comment: Are you running that as root – or as normal user? In the latter case: I doubt the system will let you write to `/sys/*` without using root. And, btw, I don't see how the error `/etc/init.d/00myfile : not found` can be related here as that path/file isn't even mentioned in the scriptlet you've posted.

Comment: i was run it with root, and i change the permission to 0755

Comment: Permission on what? Ah: You saved the quoted script as `/etc/init.d/00myfile`? Then what did start the script to throw the error? And what do you get when, at root, you run `cat /sys/device/system/cpu/sched_mc_power_savings` and `ls /sys/device/system/cpu`?

Comment: i was check everything (path and file) and im not realize that something wrong on the path, that must be /sys/devices not /sys/device. it was work now, thanks for help izzy :) :) :)

Comment: I was expecting something like that :) Glad it solved! Mind [answering your own question](/help/self-answer) and then "accepting" that answer as solution (might help others if they can identify it that way – and as side-effect earn you some rep)? While doing that, a little note on what that statement does (and what the "4" stands for) would certainly be welcome – as would the source (link) of that information, if you still have it.